# Contacts erroneously filtered out of journey

Tags: journeybuilder, accountcontactrole

I have a welcome journey set up so that when a user signs up for a free trial on our website, before receiving the set series of messages they must first pass a series of checkpoints. These are to verify that:

- the account is Active (they have not been previously blocked or
  flagged as spam) before checking
- they have not yet become a paying Client
- their industry to set them on the appropriate journey path.

Currently all contacts entering the journey are being filtered out at the first checkpoint, and I have no idea why as in previously activated journeys this filter worked and continues to function properly. 
In tests I am able to manually add a user to the database and activate the journey with the same data extensions, but for some reason the contacts entering via the form on our website are being filtered out at the first step.
Is this a marketing cloud issue, or a website issue?
Any ideas on how to fix it?